# A few problems regarding JSSOR Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, jssor

I downloaded the JSSOR Slider FULLPACK and decided to use this gallery: http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html

I inserted this into my page the same as was shown in the source. But no thumbnails or navigation arrows show.

I then changed the dimensions of the current image shown to 306x306 as this is the size of the images I will be using and changed thumbnail size to 64x64 as this is the size of my thumbnails.

The main images of the slideshow work but the thumbnails are part of the main slideshow and not below the main image. Also still no nav arrows show.

Here are 2 images to show you:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/baa18d322946581
http://www.imagebam.com/image/48d327322946583

I know the arrows don't show because they are at default values:

```
<span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px;   left: 8px;">

<span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 8px">
```

I am not sure what values I need here though.

Here is the full code for the slideshow in my html file:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 306px; height: 372px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../imag/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 306px; height: 306px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee1.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee1_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee3.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee3_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee12.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee12_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee16.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee16_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee17.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee17_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee18.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee18_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee19.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee19_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee25.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee25_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee26.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee26_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../images/dundee27.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../images/thumbs/dundee27_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>


    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <style>
        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssora05l              (normal)
        .jssora05r              (normal)
        .jssora05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05ldn            (mousedown)
        .jssora05rdn            (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora05l, .jssora05r, .jssora05ldn, .jssora05rdn
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            background: url(../images/a17.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
        .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
        .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
        .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
        .jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
        .jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
    </style>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 8px">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position: absolute; width: 306px; height: 64px; left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
            /*
            .jssort01 .p           (normal)
            .jssort01 .p:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssort01 .pav           (active)
            .jssort01 .pav:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssort01 .pdn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssort01 .w {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .jssort01 .c {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 64px;
                height: 64px;
                border: #000 2px solid;
            }

            .jssort01 .p:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav .c {
                background: url(../images/t01.png) center center;
                border-width: 0px;
                top: 2px;
                left: 2px;
                width: 64px;
                height: 64px;
            }

            .jssort01 .p:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav:hover .c {
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 66px;
                height: 66px;
                border: #fff 1px solid;
            }
        </style>
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 72px; height: 72px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate></div>
                <div class=c>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">CE0832a jQuery Slider</a>
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
<img width=0 height=0 />

<!--<div id="debuginfo" style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color:Red;color:White;Padding:5px;"></div>-->
```

And here is the script code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    //Fade in L
        {$Duration: 1200, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out R
        , { $Duration: 1200, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade in R
        , { $Duration: 1200, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out L
        , { $Duration: 1200, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }

    //Fade in T
        , { $Duration: 1200, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 4, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out B
        , { $Duration: 1200, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade in B
        , { $Duration: 1200, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out T
        , { $Duration: 1200, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 4, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }

    //Fade in LR
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Cols: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 1, $ChessMode: { $Column: 3 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out LR
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Cols: 2, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 1, $ChessMode: { $Column: 3 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade in TB
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Rows: 2, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 4, $ChessMode: { $Row: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out TB
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Rows: 2, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 4, $ChessMode: { $Row: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }

    //Fade in LR Chess
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Cols: 2, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 4, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out LR Chess
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Cols: 2, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 8, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade in TB Chess
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Rows: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 1, $ChessMode: { $Row: 3 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out TB Chess
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Rows: 2, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 2, $ChessMode: { $Row: 3 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }

    //Fade in Corners
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Cols: 2, $Rows: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $FlyDirection: 5, $ChessMode: { $Column: 3, $Row: 12 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade out Corners
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Cols: 2, $Rows: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 5, $ChessMode: { $Column: 3, $Row: 12 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $ScaleVertical: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }

    //Fade Clip in H
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 3, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade Clip out H
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 3, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$OutCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade Clip in V
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 12, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }
    //Fade Clip out V
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 12, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$OutCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
        $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
        $PauseOnHover: 3,                                //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 3

        $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
        $SlideDuration: 800,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

        $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
            $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
            $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
            $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
        },

        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 1                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        },

        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

            $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
            $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
            $Cols: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
            $Align: 360                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
        }
    };

    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (parentWidth)
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 306), 306));
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }

    ScaleSlider();

    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end
});
```

Now have these problems:

1. The black box around the thumbnails are off .....
   http://www.imagebam.com/image/cd9d52323141060
2. The slideshow is to the very left of the page ... I need it centred but none of the methods I try work.
3. I have quite a few images in the slideshow but cant see any other thumbnails than shown in the image above ... I can drag thumbnails left or right. It just snaps back to the thumbnails in the image.

Comment: please post full code here

Comment: Added the slideshow code above

Comment: and script code please

Comment: Added script code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re 1: thumbnails offset
you'd adjust css of the thumbnail skin.

re 2: center slider
use 'margin: 0 auto;' to center element

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="...;margin: 0 auto;...">
```

re 3: display pieces of
please set $Cols to 4

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

    $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
    $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
    $Cols: 4,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
    $Align: 0                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

end tag </div> of <div u="slides"...> is missing.

please replace

```
                                    </div>


                                <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
                                <style>
```

with

```
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
                                <style>
```

Comment: Ok that fixed the thumbnails showing and arrows ..... Thanks.

I have other problems which I have added to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the right arrow for starters

```
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 8px">
```

should be

```
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 8px;">
```

Also did you upload your arrow images to your img folder online. These 2 are listed in your source code on your webpage t01.png   and a17.png Upload them to your server.